# Use OpenLayers to display local raster tiles

Tags: openlayers

I have inherited a legacy webapp which displays a large set of custom maps.
It currently uses a bespoke JS implementation to display raster tiles on a canvas with markers, etc.
I want to migrate it to use a standard mapping library such as OpenLayers.

**Current functionality**

Each custom map consists of a large PNG image (thousands of pixels in width/height) which is drawn in the Mercator projection and has known bounds.

A server-side script generates a set of tiles for each of these images at 3 zoom levels:

- Zoom-level 1

  - 1:1 with original image
  - Google zoom level 16
- Zoom-level 2

  - 2:1 with original image
  - Google zoom level 15
- Zoom-level 3

  - 4:1 with original image
  - Google zoom level 14

The tiles are generated in a file/directory structure: `Z/Y/X.png`
e.g. `1/0/0.png` is the top-left (NW) tile at zoom-level 1

X and Y are sequential numbers so a 1400x1200px map at zoom-level 1 (1:1) has X=0 to 5 and Y=0 to 4.

Tiles are 256x256px except for those bottom/right tiles whose width/height is the remainder.
e.g. the bottom-right (SE) tile of a 1400x1200px map at zoom-level 1 is `1/4/5.png` and is 120x176px.

Note: the custom tile sets are also used by a mobile app to which they are downloaded and cached so changing the structure of map tiles (e.g. to TMS) is not an option.

**Question**

My question is: how do I use OpenLayers to display these custom tiles?

Additionally, the bespoke mapping engine allows overzooming of tiles at zoom-level 1 to an equivalent of Google zoom level 18.
Is it possible to also do this with OpenLayers?

**Code**

This is how far I've got with a proof-of-concept implementation:

```
// Config of the sample map (www/content/maps/sample/config.js)
const config = {
    map: {
        name: "sample"
        width: 1400,
        height: 1200,
        lat_top: 51.52568699532483,
        lon_left: -0.08205413818359376,
        lat_bottom: 51.509663955004,
        lon_right: -0.052013397216796875,
        lat_centre: 51.51767547516442,
        lon_centre: -0.06703376770019531
    }
};

const _map = 'map',
    projection: 'EPSG:3857',
    minZoom = 14,
    maxZoom = 16,
    initialZoom = 16,
    tileSize = [256,256],
    content_root = '/www/content/maps/', // location of map tiles on web server
    map_root = content_root + config.map.name+'/', 
    tiles_root = map_root + 'tiles/',
    urlTemplate = tiles_root + '{z}/{y}/{x}.png';

let map, view, tileLayer;

initMap = () => {

    const dragRotateAndZoom = new ol.interaction.DragRotateAndZoom(),
        defaultInteractions = ol.interaction.defaults(),
        interactions = defaultInteractions.extend([dragRotateAndZoom]),
        ne_bound = ol.proj.fromLonLat([config.map.lon_right, config.map.lat_top]),
        se_bound = ol.proj.fromLonLat([config.map.lon_left, config.map.lat_bottom]),
        extent = se_bound.concat(ne_bound);

    view = new ol.View({
        projection: projection,
        center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([config.map.lon_centre, config.map.lat_centre]),
        minZoom: minZoom,
        maxZoom: maxZoom,
        zoom: initialZoom
    });

    tileLayer = new ol.layer.Tile({
        extent: extent,
        source: new ol.source.XYZ({
            minZoom: minZoom,
            maxZoom: maxZoom,
            projection: projection,
            tileSize: tileSize,
            tileUrlFunction: function(tileCoord) {
                let z = tileCoord[0],
                    x = tileCoord[1],
                    y = tileCoord[2];
                
                // TODO: convert XYZ of tileCoord to custom /Z/Y/X.png tile numbering

                const result = urlTemplate
                    .replace('{z}', z.toString())
                    .replace('{x}', x.toString())
                    .replace('{y}', y.toString());

                
                return result;
            },
            wrapX: false
        })
    });

    // OpenLayers v6.9.0
    map = new ol.Map({
        interactions: interactions,
        target: _map,
        layers: [tileLayer],
        view: view
    });
}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", initMap);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To support fractional tiles at the bottom and right you would need to base your source on Zoomify or IIIF.  That has worked for me with a single zoom level, in your case I think you would need

```
    const source = new ol.source.IIIF({
        size: [config.map.width, config.map.height],
        extent: extent,
        projection: projection,
        tileSize: tileSize,
        resolutions: [1, 2, 4],
    });
    source.setTileUrlFunction(function(tileCoord) {
        let z = tileCoord[0],
            x = tileCoord[1],
            y = tileCoord[2];
        const result = urlTemplate
            .replace('{z}', z.toString())
            .replace('{x}', x.toString())
            .replace('{y}', y.toString());
        return result;
    });
```