# Wrong tile resolution when using OpenLayers to display local raster tiles

Tags: openlayers, openstreetmap

Based on [the answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/442190/86167) given to [Use OpenLayers to display local raster tiles](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/442180/86167), I have created a prototype implementation using OpenLayers (v7) with an IIIF tile source to display a set of custom tiles.

However, the scaling of the tiles is slightly wrong, as is the extent of the map.

My proof-of-concept code displays a set of tiles which are generated from a 2000x2000px image I captured of an OSM map of London with a GPX route overlay.
There are 3 zoom levels of tiles which are hosted in an S3 bucket.
I've also loaded in the actual OSM map tiles in a different layer using `ol.source.OSM`.
The custom tiles containing the GPX overlay are too small and do not line up with the OSM layer.

Here's the JS code:

```js
//sample map config
const config = {
    name: 'z_london_test',
    map:{
        width: 2000, // Map image width in pixels
        height: 2000, // Map image height in pixels
        lat_top: 51.449620948774374, // Latitude of North bound of map
        lon_left: -0.11981964111328126, // Longitude of West bound of map
        lat_bottom: 51.42286816395111, // Latitude of South bound of map
        lon_right: -0.07690429687500001, // Longitude of East bound of map
        lat_centre: 51.43624455636274, //map centre
        lon_centre: -0.09836196899414064
    }
}


const _map = 'map',
    projection = 'EPSG:3857',
    minZoom = 14,
    maxZoom = 16,
    initialZoom = 16,
    tileWidth = 256,
    tileHeight = 256,
    tileSize = [tileWidth,tileHeight],
    content_root = 'https://workingedge-public-test-bucket.s3.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/'+config.name+'/',
    tiles_root = content_root + 'tiles/',
    urlTemplate = tiles_root + '{z}/{y}/{x}.png';

let map, view, tileLayer, geolocation;


initMap = () => {

    const ne_bound = ol.proj.fromLonLat([config.map.lon_right, config.map.lat_top]),
        se_bound = ol.proj.fromLonLat([config.map.lon_left, config.map.lat_bottom]),
        extent = se_bound.concat(ne_bound);

    view = new ol.View({
        projection: projection,
        center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([config.map.lon_centre, config.map.lat_centre]),
        minZoom: minZoom,
        maxZoom: maxZoom,
        zoom: initialZoom,
        extent: extent
    });


    const source = new ol.source.IIIF({
        size: [config.map.width, config.map.height],
        extent: extent,
        projection: projection,
        tileSize: tileSize,
        resolutions: [1, 2, 4],
    });

    source.setTileUrlFunction(function(tileCoord) {
        let z = tileCoord[0],
            x = tileCoord[1],
            y = tileCoord[2];
        const result = urlTemplate
            .replace('{z}', z.toString())
            .replace('{x}', x.toString())
            .replace('{y}', y.toString());
        return result;
    });

    tileLayer = new ol.layer.Tile({
        title: 'Tile Layer',
        type: 'overlay',
        visible: true,
        extent: extent,
        source: source
    });

    const overLayLayers = [
        tileLayer,
    ];

    const overlayGroup = new ol.layer.Group({
        title: 'Tile Map',
        combine: true,
        layers: overLayLayers
    })

    // Base
    const osmLayer = new ol.layer.Tile({
        title: 'OpenStreetMap',
        type: 'base',
        source: new ol.source.OSM()
    })

    const baseLayers = [
        osmLayer,
    ];

    const baseGroup = new ol.layer.Group({
        title: 'OSM',
        combine: true,
        visible: true,
        layers: baseLayers
    })

    map = new ol.Map({
        target: _map,
        layers: [baseGroup, overlayGroup],
        view: view
    });

    const layerSwitcher = new ol.control.LayerSwitcher({
        reverse: true,
        groupSelectStyle: 'group'
    });
    map.addControl(layerSwitcher);
}


init = () => {
    initMap();
}

$(document).ready(init);
```

How can I fix this so the custom tiles align with the OSM layer and the map bounds are constrained to the extent of the custom tiles?

For ease of demonstration, I've created a CodePen containing the above code to illustrate this: https://codepen.io/dpa99c/pen/jOxogqX

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you only have tiles for a single zoom level I got it to work by setting the resolution for for that, then in the urlFunction added one to the tileCoord[0] as your tiles urls have z set to 1

```
const source = new ol.source.IIIF({
    size: [config.map.width, config.map.height],
    extent: extent,
    projection: projection,
    tileSize: tileSize,
    resolutions: [(extent[2] - extent[0]) / config.map.width],
});

source.setTileUrlFunction(function(tileCoord) {
    let z = tileCoord[0] + 1,
        x = tileCoord[1],
        y = tileCoord[2];
    const result = urlTemplate
        .replace('{z}', z.toString())
        .replace('{x}', x.toString())
        .replace('{y}', y.toString());
    return result;
});
```

https://codepen.io/mike-000/pen/KKRjQba